# Finding number of possibilities of n number of r combinations of which x can be unique behavior

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

> I have say 5 alphabets altogether (a, b, c, d, e) out of which 3 (a,b,c) are from Bag 'A' and 2 (d,e) are from Bag 'B'
>   I want all possible combination of 3 alphabets of these 5. so I used permutations 5P3 = 60
>   a b   c
>   a b   d
>   a b   e
>   a c   b
>   a c   d and so on
>
> Out of these 60 possible combinations, i want to find out the number of possible combinations of which involves 2 alphabets from Bag 'B' (d,e).
>   example,
>   b d e
>   c e d
>
> Is there a formula to find out this.
>
> Note: as mentioned above if it is for 5 alphabets it is possible to find out manually. But if it involves more number, it is very difficult to find out manually, Have to find out a way to do it based on formula alone.
>
> Can someone throw some light on my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a selection of size $n$ that has $x$ from Bag $B$ and the rest from Bag $A$.

First pick your Bag $B$ letters. You need $x$ of them.

$$\binom{\text{# of letters in Bag }B}{x}$$

Then you need to pick the remainder from $A$.

$$\binom{\text{# of letters in Bag }A}{n-x}$$

So it's

$$\binom{\text{# of letters in Bag }B}{x}\binom{\text{# of letters in Bag }A}{n-x}$$

In your specific example,
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{3-2}=3$$

This gives the number if their order isn't relevant. If the order is relevant, you just multiply by $n!$ to get all permutations for each combination. In your case $3\cdot3!=18$.

Comment: thank you RandomUser. This formula is working!!

Comment: RandomUser, could you explain how you arrive at this formula?

Comment: @Navin The answer pretty much walks through my thought process. If you have a specific question about something that's unclear, I can try to answer it.